# Error in "include" not causing standard C library to be accessed

Tags: c, path, include

error in vs code with #include path heres the error code:

> #include errors detected. Please update your includePath. Squiggles
> are disabled for this translation unit
> (C:\Users\lafem\hello.c).C/C++(1696) cannot open source file
> "stdio.h". Please run the 'Select IntelliSense Configuration...'
> command to locate your system headers.C/C++(1696)

C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    printf("Hello, World\n");
}
```

I expected it to run with no errors and print hello world but I got the error message above

Comment: Does it compile?

Comment: Yes It just doesn't run in the text editor there is a squiggle under the include tag and stdio.h

Comment: The error message is telling you what to do.

Comment: If the compiler accepts it, that's the important part, not a too-smart-for-its-own-good editor not being configured right. Looks like the error message has some advice for getting it set up, though...

Comment: Did you do as directed? You didn't mention anything about what you found